# Where is  DOS command prompt in Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7

EDIT:

In c:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe

I am in Windows 7.

I ran a Windows Search on:

```
DOS
MS-DOS
TERMINAL
COMMAND 
PROMPT
```

Comment: It's not a DOS command prompt, it's the Windows command shell.  (32-bit versions of Windows 7 do also have the DOS command shell, command.com, but this doesn't appear to be what you want.)

Answer (score 3):

Just do `start -> run -> cmd`
It should do the trick.

create a shortcut on desktop of `c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` and then set properties ?

Comment: Or even Windows Key + R -> cmd

Comment: I know but I need to set the properties tab on the actual prompt so I don't have to cd every time to my C++ directory

Comment: Actually the path is at the top of the windows..it is in c:\Windows\system32

Comment: @stack.user.0 how does it make a difference ?

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly, but it sounds like you want a shortcut to opening a command prompt at a certain directory. If so, then when browsing directories in Windows Explorer, hold down your shift key while right clicking the target directory, then you'll get a context menu option "Open Command Window here". This saves you having to "cd every time".

Comment: To add on, remember that Windows 7 comes with Powershell, and that is (depending on your task) often a superior replacement to cmd.  Also, with cmd you can use /k to carry out a command first.  So, for example, you could make a shortcut with a target of C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /K cd c:\Python27